# The mysterious disappearance of admob

Tags: android, cordova, admob

Some time ago stopped banner displayed.
Strange, but even now instead of the test banner black rectangle.
No action in the settings of advertising I did not. Also, I did not change the application code.

[image: AdMob Network report]

I used https://github.com/floatinghotpot/cordova-plugin-admob

With what it can be connected?

Big thanks.

Comment: have You added the new Admob library, that has moved to googles play service package or the old Admob library?

Comment: which version you are using? could it be that your admob account is locked?

Comment: @Opiatefuchs, I think I used the old library.

Comment: @StefanBeike Where can I see if my account is blocked?

Comment: you get a mail and in admob you will get a message after login. I dont think that your account is locked.

Comment: @StefanBeike I don't get email or message with notification of account blocking.

Comment: Don´t know if this is the reason, but You have to update Your Admob library to the new one AND get the new Admob Ad Id for Your app...